# How to configure custom brackets for markdown for `@codemirror/closebrackets`?

Tags: codemirror

I am making a markdown editor with CodeMirror 6  and I want to autoclose such signs as '`' or '*' or '_', not only {('". So far reading the documentation I can't figure out where should I put the config object ```` {brackets:["(", "[", '{', "'", '"', '```', '*','_',]} ````

My current config looks like this

```
const startState = EditorState.create({
    doc: page.text
    extensions: [
        keymap.of([...defaultKeymap, ...historyKeymap, ...closeBracketsKeymap, ...markdownKeymap, indentWithTab]),
        history(),
        closeBrackets(),
        indentOnInput(),
        bracketMatching(),
        defaultHighlightStyle.fallback,
        markdown({
            base: markdownLanguage,
            codeLanguages: languages,
            addKeymap: true,
        }),
        placeholder('Mark dowm something juicy ')
        bollsPadTheme,
        syntaxHighlighting,
        EditorView.lineWrapping,
        EditorView.updateListener.of(do(update)
            if update.changes
                handleChange && handleChange(update.state)
        )
    ]
})

editorView = new EditorView({
    state: startState,
    parent: self
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Add markdownLanguage.data.of({closeBrackets: {brackets: ...}}) to your configuration.

````
const startState = EditorState.create({
    doc: page.text
    extensions: [
        ...
        markdown({
            base: markdownLanguage,
            codeLanguages: languages,
            addKeymap: true,
        }),
        markdownLanguage.data.of({closeBrackets: {brackets: ["(", "[", '{', "'", '"', '`', '```', '*', '**', '_', '__']}}),    # Add this
        ...

    ]
})
````